# Replace the domain controller without copying the AD

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller

we might have some special terms to do with replacing our DC.
The current DC is running on an old machine with Windows Server 2003. As of the GPOs we aren't able to manage all new computers and as the machine also is pretty old we decided to replace our DC.
The problem we are facing is that our backup DC on some point has, because of an configuration fault, done some mess to our PDC. So we want to set up the new PDC from scratch but keep the domain name.

So short list of todos:

- set up new DC
- create groups, users etc (not copy from old one)
- keep the domain name
- replace old DC with new one

We are not sure whether we are facing some problems. Anyone some hints or help how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there's no such thing as a PDC or a BDC anymore, and hasn't been for a long time.

Secondly, the easiest way to replace a domain controller is to build a new server, promote it to a domain controller and allow the Active Directory databases to replicate over.  If necessary, the FSMO roles can be transferred (or seized) to the new domain controller.

Finally, if you are just completely replacing your domain (which it sounds like), then there's no need for any special steps.  Just power off the existing domain controller(s) or (disconnect them from the network if you prefer), and create your new domain.  Using the same name for the new domain you create doesn't matter much - the domains are different and the domain controllers from each domain won't be able to replicate with domain controllers from the other domain.  Of course, this also means you'll have to totally create everything in Active Directory from scratch, and join any member computers to the new domain, but it sounds like you know that already.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i originally haven't learned that and i was forced to be head of this project. I know that PDC/BDC are pretty old naming but I hoped it makes it much clrearer. We know that we need to begin from scratch and join each computer.(btw thats the badest part). We just have worried about having trouble with the same domains name. I know how to build a domain roughly but replacing is new to me. Thanks for your answer. I feel much more comfortable now.